# Как отправить запрос POST JSON через консоль c помощью СURL в Windows 10 и получить ответ JSON?

Tags: json, windows, post, curl

CURL работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не смог найти как отправить.

Нашёл вот это:

```
curl -d '{"name": "value", "name": "value"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://...
```

Не работает.

Хотя в POSTMAN всё работает! Жаль только что мне надо через консоль, а не через POSTMAN.

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из ответов на других ресурсах, так же выяснилось, что `curl --location --request POST 'google.com' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'name=value' --data-urlencode 'last_name=value'** и **curl -X POST -d '{"name": "value", "name": "value"}' -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://` тоже не работает.

Comment: Народ с линукса - нечего закрывать, всё отлично воспроизводится. Винда не считает апострофы кавычками.

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение:

```bsh
-d "{ \"user\": \"xxxx\", \"key\":  \"xxx\"}"
```